# Make my ASP.Net app run securely (https instead of http)

Tags: asp.net, https

I have an ASP.Net MVC boilerplate app that runs [locally] on localhost:6840 (http://localhost:6840), so its unsecure.

I'd like to test a 3rd party tool that only works with secure websites even when the website is run locally (on localhost) I'd like know how do I make my localhost secure i.e. https://localhost:6840 instead of http://localhost:6840

Note that I'm using IIS Express and I followed [this tutorial](https://dotnetcodr.com/2015/09/18/how-to-enable-ssl-for-a-net-project-in-visual-studio/) but it didn't work!

Comment: What web server are you using when running the application locally?  (IIS, IIS Express, Kestrel, etc.)

Comment: @David IIS Express (edited question now)

Comment: VS has a tunnel option that allows you to create a publically accessible domain for this type of thing.  [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/custom-connectors/port-tunneling) might help.